# Can't Remove Folder with Powershell But Can with Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

I'm trying to delete a folder in an install script using PowerShell. The script copies a bunch of files to a distribution folder (using RoboCopy) and then cleans up superfluous files and folders.

I seem to be unable to use PowerShell to delete a folder name `c:\installs\wwhelp\Editors\.vs` even after having set permissions in the Powershell Console running as admin.

I essentially do this after copying and cleaning out the .vs folder:

```
set source=\wwapps\wwhelp
set target=\installs\wwhelp
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted

robocopy $source\Editors $target\Editors /MIR
deletefiles $target\Editors\.vs\*.* -r -f   <-- deletes files & folder recursively
rd  $target\Editors\.vs
```

This fails with:

> *rd : Cannot remove item `C:\installs\wwhelp\editors\.vs`: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.*

The folder is empty and I'm running as admin and I've set the execution policy. If I create a folder called `vs` in the same folder structure the remove works.

Likewise running the `rd` command in the command window with Admin works.

Any ideas why I get a security exception on a folder that starts with a `.` in Powershell?

Comment: `.vs` is a folder? Somewhere the \ seems to have gone missing. Can you try  `rd c:\\installs\\wwhelp\\editors\\.vs`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers You don't need to escape ``\`` when using `rd`

Comment: @DavidPostill - the folder is \.vs but the error message shows editors.vs. That's actually all I was referring to.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers It doesn't matter. `md f:\test\.vs` followed by `rd f:\test\.vs` works as expected with no error messages - in both cmd and powershell. The OP has a different problem than escaping anything.

Comment: I can't argue with that. If OP should happen to read your comment and provide additional information I'll remove my bogus comments.

Comment: Ok maybe I do have a different problem but I'm not sure what it could be. The files are copied by RoboCopy, so there's nothing locked in there - they copied after all. Disk permissions are fine - I'm running as admin and set execution policy. I can also confirm that if I create do md .vs and rd .vs it works, but I don't know what else would be causing this problem. The error message I posted was not correct - the \ before the .vs folder is there but SO is truncating it when rendering for some reason.

Comment: Finally if I run the equivalent code with a batch file it works. I've since switched back the batch file, but I'd like to understand why the PS script  isn't working running essentially the EXACT same logic under the same account and maxed out permissions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove files/folders that start with `.`, you have to use the `-Force` parameter.

That's because PowerShell is treating them as read-only/hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem trying to delete a project I created in wrong folder with dotnet CLI. In my case .vs is a hidden folder, so I used rd with -force switch to remove it.